# Is it possible to combine two patterns, one with a match guard, in the same match arm?

Tags: rust

I want to check if a string contains '$' and if there is something after the '$':

I tried this code:

```
fn test(s: String) {
    match s.find('$') {
        None | (Some(pos) if pos == s.len() - 1) => {
          expr1();
        }
        _ => { expr2(); }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't compile:

> ```
> error: expected one of `)` or `,`, found `if`
> ```

Is it impossible to combine `None` and `Some` in one match-arm?

If so, is there a simple way to not duplicate `expr1()` except moving it into a separate function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is **impossible** to have the match-guard (the `if` thingy) apply to only one pattern alternative (the things separated by `|` symbols). There is only one match-guard per arm and it applies to all patterns of that arm.

However, there are many solutions for your specific problem. For example:

```
if s.find('$').map(|i| i != s.len() - 1).unwrap_or(false) {
    expr2();
} else {
    expr1();
}
```

Comment: This works, but relies on the fact that `$` is ASCII and thus takes up one byte. A more general solution might use [`char::len_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.len_utf8): `i != s.len() - 'c'.len_utf8()`.

Comment: I want in on the code golf: `s.chars().skip_while(|i| i != '$').skip(1).next().is_some()` is much clearer than any index computations imo